# shell script to ips from hosts file using hostname

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I have a list of hostnames and i would like to get the ips from the hosts file. However, when I run the script I wrote I only get the ip of the final hostname.

Can anybody spot the obvious error I cannot? Thanks.

```
!/bin/ksh

for hostname in `sort /home/steveo/out_stream.txt`
do
    #extract hostnames from hosts file
    ip=`grep -i $hostname /etc/hosts | awk '{print $1}'`
    echo ${hostname} ${ip} >>ip_hostname_list.txt
done

echo "press RETURN \c";read dummy;clear

$ more ip_hostname_list.txt

arq852mux1_8k
arq852mux2_8k 
arq854mux1_8k 
arq854mux2_8k 
arq898mux1_8k
arq898mux2_8k
arq902mux1_8k
arq902mux2_8k 172.27.228.70
```

Comment: The script works for me. Are you sure the hostnames are in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: yes they are definitely in there i have run a manual grep to check that! thats why i was convinced there was an error in the script

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. :)

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script, so it will show the commands it's executing with all the variables expanded.

Comment: the set -x showed a \r in the script. when i googled this its a windows end of line entry from where i copied the hostname file from. i ran the dos2unix on the hostname list and it did the trick. Thanks for your help :)